# How to connect to mysql or postgresql database running on a cloud server with appscripts?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, google-apps-script

I am trying to connect to a `postgresql` server, which is currently running on a `google cloud machine` with `appscripts`. I want to push the data from the google spreadsheet to that postgresql database, I have tried to achieve this with the help of `jdbc` documentation provided in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc). I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find anything related to postgresql, so i tried connecting with mysql database running on the same server but it is showing the error

[image]
The code which I tried for connecting to mysql looks like

```
var server = 'ipaddress'
var dbName = 'dbname'
var username = 'db name'
var password = 'password'
var port = 3306
var url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + server + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
function myFunction() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password)
  Logger.log(url);
  Logger.log(conn);
  conn.close();
}
```

My current code for postgresql looks like

```
var dbName = 'dbname'
var username = 'username'
var password = 'password'
var port = 5432
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'jdbc:postgresql://' + server + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password)
  Logger.log(url);
  Logger.log(conn);
  conn.close();
}
```

I am getting the error

[image]

How to solve this? and is it even possible to connect to postgresql with appscripts?
PS I am able to connect to the same database with same credentials with pgadmin

Answer (score 1):

From Apps Script documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) :

> The JDBC service supports Google Cloud SQL MySQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL
> Server, and Oracle databases.

So PostgreSQL is not yet supported.

For the MySQL connection, from the error message, it is clear that your credentials seems wrong. Check it by login to your database remote server via terminal

```
mysql -u <username> -p -h <ip_address>
```

or connect it via Database Tools like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)

Comment: I have double checked the credentials they are not wrong, I am able to connect with mysql workbench without any difficulty.

Comment: Have you tried `Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(url)` instead of `Jdbc.getConnection(url)` ? Because the second method requires you to allow-list a set of IP ranges for access to your database.

Comment: @PurushothamanU did using [`Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(url, info)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getcloudsqlconnectionurl,-info) work for you?

Comment: @Aerials, I tried it, but it asked for credit card for using the GoogleCloudSql database and I didn't want to provide my card details.

Comment: Clarify this please: your mysql db is being served from where? Does that server have a firewall?